# How to take space-separated numbers as input on the same line?

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-input

```
a, b = int(input(), int(input())
print(a)
print(b)
```

I want to take two inputs on the same line as `640 48` but I am getting an ERROR:

```
invalid literal for int() with base 10 : '640 480'
```

Answer (score 6):

`input()` does nothing more than read an entire line (up to but stripping the final newline) and return that, as a string.

You can process that string however you want. For instance if you want your input to be of the form `<number1> <number2>` you can just split the result of `input()` then interpret each segment as an integer:

```py
>>> a, b = map(int, input().split())
640 480
>>> a
640
>>> b
480
```